# Validar Items de RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Hola Compañeros necesito de su ayuda, estoy intentando validar un `RecyclerView`, para poder identificar cuando un `RecyclerView` está vacío. Intenté con un `getItemCount`, también con un `myRecyclerView.getAdapter.getItemCount`, pero al cargar y mostrarlo en un *Toast* el resultado sale 0; por más que hayan o no datos en el *Recycler*. ¿Podrían ayudarme? este es mi código:

```
public class Productos extends Fragment {


    private RecyclerView mList;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private List<ProductoBean> ProList;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_productos, container, false );


        mList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.ListaProductos );



        adapter = new ProductoAdapter( getActivity(), ProList );
        adapter.setHasStableIds( true );

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( getActivity() );
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation( LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL );
        dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration( mList.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation() );

        mList.setHasFixedSize( true );

        mList.setLayoutManager( linearLayoutManager );

        mList.addItemDecoration( dividerItemDecoration );


        mList.setAdapter( adapter );




       // AQUI LLAMO EL MÉTODO


       Toast.makeText( getActivity(), ""+adapter.getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();



        return rootView;
    }



    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias men , pero lo que pasa que eso funciona siempre en cuando el Adapter Ya cargue todo , es decir cuando ya cargo en OnCreate ! , hay alguna manera de poner ese metodo en el Oncreate sin que salga 0? u otra solución? Help me please :D , @Elenasys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener la cantidad de elementos usando el `LinearLayoutManager` :

```
if(linearLayoutManager .getItemCount() == 0 ){
             Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "No contiene elementos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();  
}
```

o también puedes obtener la cantidad de elementos después de terminar `onCreate()`, esto sería en `onResume()`  de esta forma:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

  if (adapter.getItemCount() == 0){
     Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "No contiene elementos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();    
   }else{     
      Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "Existen "+adapter.getItemCount() + " elementos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();    
   }

}
```